# [COVERITY][C++] Non-static class member "A._M_elems" is not initialized in this constructor nor in any functions that it calls

Tags: c++11, constructor, initialization, coverity

I am having an issue with a coverity warning that occurs in the constructor of my C++11 class.

In the class `Model`, I define the type `Trajectory` and declare it privately.

```
template<unsigned int T, unsigned int K>
class Model
{
public:
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, DEGREE, AXIS> State;
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, AXIS_COUNT, K> Sample;
    typedef std::array<std::array<Sample, T>, DEGREE> Trajectory;

private:
    Settings _settings;
    State _state;
    Trajectory _trajectory;

...
```

Later in the constructor section I define two constructors, the second one inherits from the first one. In the first one, I initialize the `_trajectory` variable in the double for loop.

```
...

public:
    Model(const Settings& settings, const State& initialState) :
     _settings(settings),
     _state(initialState)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DEGREE; i++)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < T; j++)
                _trajectory[i][j].setZero();
    };
    Model(const Settings& settings) :
     Model(settings, State::Zero()){};

    ~Model() = default;

...
```

This class is called by a handler which initializes `Model` with the second constructor. Everything works fine, however, once I run the coverity check, I receive the following error.

```
Non-static class member "_trajectory._M_elems" is not initialized in this constructor nor in any functions that it calls.
```

It is called at the line `Model(settings, State::Zero()){};`

I have tried many options but I cannot figure out how to initialize `_trajectory` properly without receiving this error.

I have tried this:

```
public:
    Model(const Settings& settings, const State& initialState) :
     _settings(settings),
     _state(initialState),
     _trajectory({})
```

this

```
public:
    Model(const Settings& settings, const State& initialState) :
     _settings(settings),
     _state(initialState),
     _trajectory({{}})
```

this

```
public:
    Model(const Settings& settings, const State& initialState) :
     _settings(settings),
     _state(initialState),
     _trajectory(Trajectory{{}})
```

and other combinations. None works.

Waiting for some legend to give me a hint.

Comment: What if you put the "brace-or-equal-initializer" on the definition of the NSDM instead of in the ctor-initializer-list?  That is, the last line in your first code snippet becomes `Trajectory _trajectory{};`

Comment: @BenVoigt, thank you for the suggestion, but it did not work. I added `Trajectory _trajectory{};`.

Comment: that was a change to your existing code (add `{}`) not a completely new line of code.